i dont understand where the file .j2 come from? /fibre_study /fibre_cpp/
i fork a code from https://github.com/embedded-idea/fibre_study.git
/*[# This is the original template, thus the warning below does not apply to this file #]

============================ WARNING ============================
==== This is an autogenerated file.                          ====
==== Any changes to this file will be lost when recompiling. ====
=================================================================

This file contains base classes that correspond to the interfaces defined in
your interface file. The objects you publish should inherit from these
interfaces.


*/
it said, autogenerated file . but i can`t find any command to generate .j2 file
can some tell me ,how the .j2 file come from？

It literally says

This is the original template, thus the warning below does not apply to this file

The warning is for the file generated from the .j2 file.

wow，i am so silly 。
